# Is it possible to use Task Scheduler to open a VBS file without a command window?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, vbscript

```
set objShell = createobject("wscript.shell")  
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"" ""-SignatureUpdate""") , 0 <br>

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\Balloontip.vbs" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The above is used in a VBS file. When I use Task Scheduler to run it, a command window will appear and then disappear immediately. Is it possible to run it without any command window? 
If I use the 'Matthew_Wai' user account, the .vbs file can be run with a momentary window.
But if I use 'SYSTEM' as shown below, the .vbs file cannot be run with no window and error message (nothing happens at all).
(I can change my display language to English if need be.)
[image]

Comment: Why can't you run the vbs script? (Did you try running cscript.exe with your vbs script as an argument?) Also, if you are just wanting to open the txt file in notepad, you can run notepad directly and pass the txt file as the argument.

Comment: Task Scheduler cannot directly run a VBS file. Can you teach me how to use Task Scheduler to run cscript.exe with my vbs script as an argument? Actually, the vbs script is used to run a bat file rather than a txt file.

Comment: When you create a task to start a program, it should ask for the program which is  in your system32 folder, (ie normally  c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe) and it you ask for arguments and you need to enter the full path name of your script file.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But when it runs, a command window will still appear and then disappear immediately. Is it inevitable when Task Scheduler runs a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `wscript.exe` to run the script, instead of `cscript.exe`

Comment: Bingo! That’s what I want. It works perfectly. No command window appears. Thank you very much, w32sh!

Answer (score 0):

I typically configure the tasks that I create within `Task Scheduler` to utilize the built-in `System` account and also check the box to mark them as `Hidden`.  As a result, I never see any interface appear on the screen:

[image: Task Scheduler]

Comment: Note that the Hidden checkbox applies to whether the task shows up in the Task Scheduler window when *View | Show Hidden Tasks* is off.

Comment: @ Run5k, I had done as you said, but the file could not be run. I have edited my question. Please see it again.

Comment: Before you said that it was running, but a window would briefly appear... but now it isn't running at all?  If the file couldn't be run, what type of error (if any) are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have edited my question. Please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

The Task Scheduler will happily open a file with the default handler if the task runs only when the user is logged on, i.e. with access to the desktop. (Otherwise the handler will run, but the window it creates will be in session 0 with all the invisible system stuff.)

Therefore, a configuration like this does exactly what you want:

[image: execute the file itself]

One downside: Task Scheduler doesn't like spaces in the path, even if you quote it, so if your file's full location has a space, you might have to use the abbreviated [8.3 name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for one or more path components.

Comment: Actually I have to run a .vbs file rather than a .txt file. I have edited my question. See it again.

Comment: @MatthewWai For what it's worth, running a VBS script also works for me as long as the default handler for that file type is `wscript`. I'm glad the other answer works for you.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the difference between `wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe`?

Comment: @MatthewWai `cscript` is designed to run scripts in a **c**onsole, while `wscript` is marked as being an application that can create **w**indows. ([Relevant SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8678441/2825369))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html) utility to run a script without the console window appearing by using the `/NOCONSOLE` switch.